# How can I sum up the values from a column and then separate them in different columns?

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm just a beginner with R and I've been having some trouble organising my data set.

I have a particular problem. I'm working with a data set from an agricultural survey. In this data set, subjects (farms) have different plots and in those plots have different crops. Something like this

| Subject | CropName | Area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Corn | 2 |
| A | Carrots | 2 |
| A | Avocado | 0,5 |
| A | Corn | 1 |
| B | Grapes | 2 |
| C | Carrots | 3 |

As you can see, not all farms have the same crops and the same crops can be found in different plots of the same farm.

What I want to do is to sum up the values of each crop in a farm and separate them in different columns, to obtain only one observation per farm. Which will make my life easier on the analysis phase.

Something like this:

| Subject | Corn | Carrots | Avocado | Grapes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | **3** | 2 | 0.5 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| C | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

I've have not idea how to do it. I'm open to suggestions about how my code should look like.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`, what you have tried so far, and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

You can create this table, like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Subject = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C"),
  CropName = c("Corn","Carrots",
               "Avocado","Corn","Grapes","Carrots"),
  Area = c("2", "2", "0.5", "1", "2", "3"))

head(df1)
#   Subject CropName Area
# 1       A     Corn    2
# 2       A  Carrots    2
# 3       A  Avocado  0.5
# 4       A     Corn    1
# 5       B   Grapes    2
# 6       C  Carrots    3 

df1 %>% mutate(Area = as.numeric(Area)) %>% # change to number
  group_by(CropName, Subject) %>%  # group by what's wanted as names
  summarise(Area = sum(Area)) %>%  # where the values will come from
  spread(CropName, Area, fill = 0) # render the spread, fill with 0
```

The console output will render the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Subject Avocado Carrots  Corn Grapes
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A           0.5       2     3      0
2 B           0         0     0      2
3 C           0         3     0      0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kat. Next time I will follow your advice!